# Determine if (1,2,0) is in the Span

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We are approaching complex numbers and complex spaces and I am confused with both of them and their relationship to linear algebra. I have a question from a lecture slide: Working in C^3, determine if (1,2,0) is in span((i,0,0),(i,i,0),(i,i,i)).
There is a tip to set (1,2,0) equal to the span, but I am not sure if I'm to make an augmented matrix from there or what.

Comment: You're working in $\Bbb C^3$, sure., but *over what field*?  If over the field $\Bbb C$, then yes (*you may note that the span is the same as the span of $(1,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,1,1)$ and think the same way as for the problem in $\Bbb R^3$ instead*).  If over the field $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb Q$, then no, as any entry of any vector in the span will be either zero or be strictly imaginary.

Comment: This is a good time to reiterate the point that to adequately identify a vector space, you must not only refer to the underlying set, you must also define what "vector addition" you are using and what scalar field you are using as well as what scalar multiplication you are using.  If such information is left out, we usually assume that it is the canonical choices, but both $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$ are common choices for the scalar field of the vector space $\Bbb C^3$.  If $\Bbb R$ is used, then it is a six-dimensional space, and if $\Bbb C$ is used then it is a three-dimensional space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

Assuming your field is $\mathbb{C}$, the question is asking if you can find $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $$a(i,0,0)+b(i,i,0)+c(i,i,i) = (1,2,0)$$

You might like to determine what is $c$ first by comparing the third component, then determine $b$ and $a$.